# Looking for a SPARQL query that creates a compact table

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have some RDF data that make use of the new [Data Cube vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-vocab-data-cube-20130312/). For visualization, I need the data as a flat and compact table. But I fail at finding the right SPARQL query that does this.

I will try to give a minimal example...

Given the following RDF data:

```
o1
 :year "2007";
 :fruit :apples;
 :harvest "200";
 .
o2
 :year "2007";
 :fruit :pears;
 :harvest "180";
 . 
o3
 :year "2008";
 :fruit :apples;
 :harvest "205";
.
o4
 :year "2008";
 :fruit :pears;
 :harvest "176";
.
```

Is there a SPARQL query that can return the data as the following table?

```
Year | Apples | Pears
2007 | 200    | 180
2008 | 205    | 176
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select ?year (sample(?num_apples) as ?apples) (sample(?num_pears) as ?pears)
where
{
    { ?s :year ?year ; :fruit :apples; :harvest ?num_apples }
    union
    { ?s :year ?year ; :fruit :pears; :harvest ?num_pears }
}
group by ?year
```

You could use `sum()` or `avg()` rather than `sample()`, which would make more sense if you have multiple harvest figures.

(Warning: your values are strings rather than numbers!)

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks a lot! So the trick is to use an aggregate function. That makes a lot of sense, in hindsight.

Yes, I know I omitted the data type specifications. I did that to keep the example simple. But this approach works well with my real data. The only thing I needed to change was to use an sql: prefix before the SAMPLE function, because I use a Virtuoso endpoint.